# Flask app crashes "Restarting with reloader....socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use

Tags: python, flask, webserver, jinja2

In my flask app I import a file, which has python variables. I then pass this variable to html template and show it on the browser using jinja2 templating.

What I am doing here is I redirect user to a url which renders a html file and passes this python variable to jinja2 template. I update this file and change variables value time to time using a script.

When  I update my module file and change variables value, My flask app crashes.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong, I am new to web development. Also I want to know if their is anyway we can import python variable in Jinja2 template.

```
* Detected change in '/root/Tas/modules/steps.py', reloading
* Restarting with reloader
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "routes.py", line 45, in <module>
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True,use_reloader=True)
 File "/root/Tas/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
File "/root/Tas/venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 706, in   run_simple
test_socket.bind((hostname, port))
File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

My code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from forms import UpgradeForm
import subprocess
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/root/Tas/modules/')
import time
import reko
import tibbr_path
import steps

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'development key'

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/upgrade', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upgrade():
    form = UpgradeForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.validate() == False:
                    flash('All Fields are required')
                    return render_template('upgrade.html', form=form)
            else:
                    fo = open("/root/Tas/modules/reko.py", "wb")
                    print form.username.data
                            fo.write("username='%s'\npassword='%s'\npack_pack='%s'\nup_server='%s'\n" % (form.username.data, form.password.data, form.pack_pack.data, form.up_server.data))
                    fo.close()
                    return render_template('validate.html', form=form)
    elif request.method == 'GET':
            return render_template('upgrade.html', form=form)

@app.route('/exec_SNupgrade', methods=['GET'])
def exec_SNupgrade():
     os.system("/root/Tas/scripts/int_SNupgrade.py &")
     return redirect(url_for('display_step'))
     )
@app.route('/display_step', methods=['GET'])
def display_step():
    return render_template('display_step.html', up_server=reko.up_server, step1=steps.step1 , step2=steps.step2, step3=steps.step3, step4=steps.step4)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True,use_reloader=True)
```

Comment: which version are you using? In `python` it shows version `2.6`. Can you update both python and falsk versions and check it?

Comment: Updated python to 2.7 & and flask to latest version 0.10.1 but still no luck. :(

Comment: I'm having this same problem.  The server works initially and serves files correctly. But when files change, flask tries to reload. At this point, the `Address already in use` error occurs. It may be related to [this flask issue](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/1304), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

If the address is already in use change the default port

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=12345, use_reloader=True)
```

you can now access the page through `http://localhost:12345`

Comment: No I tried that already if you in logs when I update the modules file, that it detects change and try to reload and it carshes after that saying address already in use. If i dont update that module file it doest not crashes.

Comment: @user3197035 please make sure you port 12345 is not in use `nmap -p 12345 localhost`

Comment: No my port is 5000 and I also tried using port 80 and few other.

Comment: @user3197035, are you quitting the script using `ctrl+z` instead of 'ctrl+c'

Comment: I just run the script. It crashes automatically when it tries to reload(after module file gets updated.) 
    
    `* Detected change in '/root/Tas/modules/steps.py', reloading
     * Restarting with reloader`

Comment: I think you misunderstand.  The server works initially and serves files correctly.  But when files change, flask tries to reload.  At this point, the `Address already in use` error occurs.  So changing the port doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

'Address already in use' means you've got another server running on that computer that's bound to the same port. Turn it off, and you should be good to go.

Comment: No I tried that already if you in logs when I update the modules file, that it detects change and try to reload and it carshes after that saying address already in use.If i dont update that module file it does not crashes.